# Why is my bubble sort not sorting duplicates and only firing once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, bubble-sort

I'm building a sorting visualizer in React, but have encountered a slight error.
I'm using bubble sort to sort through a list of randomly generated numbers, the bars' height is indicative of their number values (600 max). I want it to sort through the entire list, but it will only shift the largest item once onClick() ... Not only that, but I'm having trouble when it comes to duplicate values. the duplicates are usually put right next to each other, and the cascade restarts after that point starting with the next largest value. If there were no duplicates generated, then I would only have to click `sort()` a bunch of times until everything shifted into the right place, so it only halfway works.

- duplicates are resetting the sort
- the `sort()` is only running once on every click

```
    sort() {

      const state = this.state.data;
      let i = 0
      let a = 0;
      let b = a + 1;        

      do {

        let aValue = this.state.data[a];
        let bValue = this.state.data[b];
        let aIndex = this.state.data.indexOf(aValue);
        let bIndex = this.state.data.indexOf(bValue); 

        function swap(a,b) {
          state.splice([aIndex], 1, b)
          state.splice([bIndex], 1, a)
        }           

              if(aValue > bValue && i <= state.length) { 
                swap(aValue, bValue)
              }
 
        a += 1;
        b += 1;
        i += 1;
     
      } while (i < state.length)

    this.setState({})
    }
```

Comment: Any change you could supply a reproducible example of your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first make a copy of the state and only work with that to have a clearer picture of what is happening – in the end of the method you were not setting the state to the result of the sort, so I added that in the solution. Then you don't need to use `indexOf` but instead you should work with the index you already have (eg `b`) – this is the reason your sort struggles with duplicates because `indexOf` finds the index of the first element with the given value in an array. Also, instead of passing the index you are passing an array of the index into the `splice` method (in my solution I use array destructuring instead of a `swap` function). In your current version you are only doing one iteration run of the bubble sort but a bubble sort needs two loops. To sort everything you will need to iterate repeatedly and skip the last n elements of the array which are already sorted. With these changes your sort method could look like this:

```js
    sort() {
      let i = 0
      const state = [...this.state.data]  

      while (i < state.length) {
        for (let b = 0; b < (state.length - i - 1); b++) {
          if (state[b] > state[b + 1]) { 
            [state[b], state[b + 1]] = [state[b + 1], state[b]]
          }
        }
 
        i += 1  
      }

      this.setState({...this.state, data: state})
    }
```

**Comment**: Sorry I misread your question in my first answer and then edited it a bunch of times.